# Trapezoidal rule error vs. composite trapezoidal rule error

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

$$f(x) = (x + 1/x)^2$$
First I evaluated the *value of integration* of $f(x)$ from $1$ to $2$.
Exact value = 4.833333…

Then I evaluated this using *trapezoidal rule*.

Answer is = 5.125

Percent relative error = -6.03%

Then I evaluated this using *composite trapezoidal rule* of 4 intervals.

Answer is = 4.477744

Percent relative error = 7.357%

In this case absolute relative error of composite trapezoidal rule is larger than trapezoidal rule. What is the reason for that?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha disagrees with your result: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%28x%2B1%2Fx%29%5E2+from+x%3D1+to+2+by+trapezoid+rule+of+4+intervals

Comment: Try using MathJax to make your formulas legible: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation. Then maybe you can show the steps of how you arrived at your answer for the compound trapezoid rule. It seems likely there is a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see if the values can be reproduced. $F(x)=\frac13x^3+2x-\frac1x$, so that $$\int_1^2f(x)dx=F(2)-F(1)=4.8333333$$

The simple trapezoidal rule gives $$\frac12(f(1)+f(2))=5.125$$

The composite trapezoidal rule with 4 segments has the formula
$$
0.25\cdot\left(\frac12f(1)+f(1.25)+f(1.5)+f(1.75)+\frac12f(2)\right)=4.85274376417
$$
This is a different value and as one could expect closer to the exact value. As the function is convex, any secant segment lies above the function. Thus any trapezoidal value has to be larger than the area under the function.

[image]